# Wordpress Woocommerce Multisite user registration error

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite, user-registration, multisite-user-management

I am a multisite user, when woocommerce is installed and a user tries to register a new account they receive an error:

"Error: Cannot create a user with an empty login name."

See the below image for reference:
[image]

I have tried to change the registration form to include the username as this is the login name, however, no matter which fields I add to the registration form I have the same error.

Is there any fix for this in Multisite? Thanx in advance!